# Django: saving date into database

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save a date into the database for an attendance system. The print statement works just fine however the date does not get saved into the database.
Please help.

models.py

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    last_here = models.DateTimeField()


class Student(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_gender = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=GENDER, default='N/A')
    student_parent_email = models.EmailField()
    attendance = models.ForeignKey(Attendance, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

views.py

```
while(num!=amount): #there are multiple students.
    stu = Student.objects.filter(squad='LearnToSwim1')[num]

    if request.POST.get(stu.student_name, '') == 'on':
        stu.attendance.last_here = datetime.today() #this does not work.

        print("Student attendance taken")
        print(stu.attendance.last_here) 

        stu.save()


    num += 1
```

Comment: firstly you are using model of **Student** to save data in **Attendance**

Comment: @c.grey yep, the two models are related. Each student has an attendance. I added the student model into the question above.

Comment: Add foreginkey to Attendance model not to Student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the `Attendance` model, not `Student` model ie `stu.attendance.save()`
ie:

```
while(num!=amount): #there are multiple students.
    stu = Student.objects.filter(squad='LearnToSwim1')[num]

    if request.POST.get(stu.student_name, '') == 'on':
        stu.attendance.last_here = datetime.today() #this does not work.

        print("Student attendance taken")
        print(stu.attendance.last_here) 

        stu.attendance.save() # here


    num += 1
```